# How to run two commands, but with a delay on the second command without stopping the first command?

Tags: bash, monitoring, benchmarking, sleep

I'm trying to do the following (on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian OS):

1. start a benchmark (`sysbench`)
2. then run some monitoring tools (`iostat` and `mpstat`) after some delay, say 5s, as a warm-up interval

So I made the following base script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in 16000 32000 64000 128000
do
  echo "max-prime = $x"
  (sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=$x --num-threads=4 run >> results.out) & (sleep 5s && mpstat >> mpstat.out & iostat >> iostat.out)
done
```

I tried some more variations of the 5th line above but `sysbench` was not being executed properly (I think because of `sleep`?). The output written in `results.out` is only this, repeated 4 times because of the loop:

```
sysbench 0.4.12: multi-threaded system evaluation benchmark

Running the test with following options:
Number of threads: 4

Doing CPU performance benchmark

Threads started!
```

How do I execute `sysbench` and run the monitoring tools after 5 seconds, without compromising `sysbench`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have an easier time of it if you put the commands on separate lines.

```
for x in 16000 32000 64000 128000
do
  echo "num of threads = $x"
  sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=$x --num-threads=4 run >> results.out &
  sleep 5s
  mpstat >> mpstat.out
  iostat >> iostat.out
done
```

You'll want to wait until the benchmark finishes before going to the next loop. I recommend putting either `wait` or `kill %%` at the end of the loop to either wait for or stop it.

Answer (score 1):

You can mix the `;` command separator with `&` to put a process in the background.

`foo & sleep 5; bar &`

In your case, you want to do this in a loop.  If you want to wait for `foo` to finish before going on to the next iteration of the loop, use `wait`.

```
for  ... ; do
    foo & sleep 5; bar
    wait
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try an extra pair of parentheses here:

```
... & (sleep 5s && (mpstat >> mpstat.out & iostat >> iostat.out))
                   ^                                           ^
```